# Use a LaTeX expression in a knitr figure caption

Tags: knitr

I am writing an .Rnw document in RStudio. I would like to be able to use latex expressions in Figure captions created by knitr.

First a code chunk for the caption:

```
<<cap_4, echo=FALSE>>=
cap <- "My figure. 
Some \textit{italics}. 
A reference to another figure: \ref{fig:other-fig}.
"
@
```

Now the plot chunk:

```
<<my-plot, echo=FALSE, fig.cap=cap>>=
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = data)
@
```

This fails to correctly render the italics or reference in the figure caption. Instead I get only part of the text (minus the first letter of the expression), e.g. instead of

> A reference to another figure: 1.

I get

> A reference to another figure: ef{fig:other-fig}.

Is it possible to use latex expressions in a knitr caption?

Comment: Most likely you need to escape the slash: `\\ref{fig:other-fig}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the slash, so that R doesn't treat the `\r` as a symbol to interpret:

```
\\ref{fig:other-fig}
```